# Is it possible to use strings.xml from one localization values folder for another similar language?

Tags: android, localization

I've been looking on Internet for this but didn't find any article/blog (probably I have been looking poorly) so I'd decided to ask question here: is it possible to use same `strings.xml` (translations) from one language folder for another language, which is very similar? To be more specific, I'd like to use translations from `values-sk` also for `values-cz` language.

I was thinking about writing a Gradle script which would make a copy of `strings.xml` file in `values-sk` folder and copy it into `values-cz` folder on build, but I'd like to know if there's an easier/out of the box solution.

Comment: creating script is only suggestion I guess. Let wait what for community opinion.

Comment: I've just sent an answer. Please check if I get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved it using Gradle script before build. In case someone's interested, I added new task in `app.gradle` (at the end of the file, but that shouldn't matter):

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(copySkStringsFileToCsFolder)
}

task copySkStringsFileToCsFolder(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Copies strings.xml from values-sk to values-cs'
    from 'src/main/res/values-sk/strings.xml'
    into 'src/main/res/values-cs'
}
```

From what I overview, it copies the file on every Sync/Build operation - works pretty neatly for me, but I am still interested in other possibilities (if there are any).
Also I would like to apologize to Czech people that I misinterpreted the code for values folder (using `-cz` instead of `-cs`) - sorry 'bout that, I didn't know I was supposed to use the other one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create both `values-sk` & `values-cz` folder in your `/res` directory of your project and then copy-paste the `strings.xml` to each. As you can see, *those will be different directories* **but with the same `strings.xml`** so, it probably should work.

After that, Android will detect that you have two different directory-strings for two different localization then, you can change, modify each one of them (If needed).